# How to restart position when date value change?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with sale quantity of my product, I would like to get an order of the sale quantity by day. The problem is with my actual request I only have the total position. I would like the position to start at 1 each time the date changes.

I need this for a bigger query, to determine the demand for products.

```
SELECT (@pos := @pos+1) pos,`sale_qty`, Date, post_id 
FROM `sale_qty` S, (SELECT @pos := 0) p 
ORDER BY `Date`ASC ,`sale_qty` ASC
```

This is what I have :

```
   pos  | sale_qty |    Date    | post_id
--------|----------|------------|--------
    1   |     0    | 2019-01-28 | 25077
    2   |     15   | 2019-01-28 | 25479
    3   |     0    | 2019-01-29 | 2077
    4   |     8    | 2019-01-29 | 25923
    5   |     13   | 2019-01-29 | 25892
    6   |     2    | 2019-01-30 | 2910
```

And what I want :

```
   pos  | sale_qty |    Date    | post_id
--------|----------|------------|--------
    1   |     0    | 2019-01-28 | 25077
    2   |     15   | 2019-01-28 | 25479
    1   |     0    | 2019-01-29 | 2077
    2   |     8    | 2019-01-29 | 25923
    3   |     13   | 2019-01-29 | 25892
    1   |     2    | 2019-01-30 | 2910
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables but you need to remember the `date` value:

```
SELECT (@pos := if(@d = date, @pos + 1,
                   if(@d := date, 1, 1)
                  )
       ) as pos,
       `sale_qty`, Date, post_id 
FROM (SELECT s.*
      FROM `sale_qty` s
      ORDER BY `Date`ASC, `sale_qty` ASC
     ) s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @d := '', @pos := 0) p ;
```

Or more simply in MySQL 8+,

```
SELECT row_number() over (partition by date order by sale_qty) as pos
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Looks like it works, but I do not have MYSQL 8+ and I do not know how to remember the date value, can you explain it to me ?

Comment: @BaptisteBoisset . . . The first solution should work on any version of MySQL.  The simpler solution is for MySQL 8+.

Comment: it works when both dates are on the same page, but if I go from page 1 to 2 the position is also reset without a date change

Comment: @BaptisteBoisset . . . Nothing in this query is doing paging.  It is simply setting the value of pos according to the rules you specify.